# how to skip quot in image src

Tags: html

so i have a image src like this `<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=key1&cid=&lt;% contact field="id" %&gt;&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=open_email&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=Test_Newsletter">`

the problem is with the "" in `contact field="id"`, so please if someone has any idea how i skip "" into this image src i will be very appreciative

Comment: You should be URL encoding the string first, where did you get this URL? What is the original URL unmodified?

Comment: The spaces aren't valid characters in a URL either. It's possible you'd need to escape those too with `%20`, but I'm wondering if this is some sort of server-generated string that's been pasted in the wrong place.

Comment: Usually there we don't send param in URL as var="val" but you can use HML encoding if needed

Answer (score 0):

Replace one of the usages of " with '.

Like `<img src='...' />` or the contact field with 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode it via javascript with `encodeURIComponent()` or manually by replacing `"` with `%22`